# Unity3D Machine Learning Setup for ML-Agents on Windows 10 with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, unity-game-engine, installation, ml-agent

I have been trying to get the [Machine Learning Setup for ML-Agents](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-with-Balance-Ball.md) for Unity 3D up and running for the past several hours, with no luck.

First I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxicgknzUG8&index=1&list=PLB5_EOMkLx_Ub1A4iHoDUx7vg37sVoL-E) video, which goes over the initial installations which are also outlined in this [GitHub](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Installation.md) repository.

Next, I moved on to part 2 of the video series ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YWts_GlHCY&index=2&list=PLB5_EOMkLx_Ub1A4iHoDUx7vg37sVoL-E)), however problems started at minute 4:48, where I realized that the tutorial was using v 0.2, while I had v 0.3.

V 0.3 has done away with the `PPO.ipynb` file shown in the video. Everything is done through `learn.py` file.

I then decided to try and follow the official Unity installation guide:

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-with-Balance-Ball.md

and got to **Training with PPO** section which I have not managed to resolve.

**the problem arises here:** The documentation states:

> To summarize, go to your command line, enter the ml-agents directory and type:
>
> ```
> python3 python/learn.py <env_file_path> --run-id=<run-identifier> --train
> ```
>
> Note: If you're using Anaconda, don't forget to activate the ml-agents
>   environment first.

I tried to run:

> python learn.py ball --run-id=ballBalance --train

but I am greeted with a number of warnings as follows:

> File "learn.py", line 9, in 
>       from unitytrainers.trainer_controller import TrainerController
>     File "C:\Users****\Downloads\ml-agents-master\python\unitytrainers__init__.py", line 1, in 
>       from .buffer import *

I have been trying to solve this error message for quite some time now. It seems that the file `learn.py` is actually being found, but somehow not being interpreted correctly?

First 9 lines of `learn.py`:

```
# # Unity ML Agents
# ## ML-Agent Learning

import logging

import os
from docopt import docopt

from unitytrainers.trainer_controller import TrainerController
```

Any guidance on how I can solve this problem would be appreciated. Would gladly give more information where needed. The steps mentioned above should replicate the problem I am experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure whether I solved the same problem. But somewhere under my errors it also told me about line 9 in learn.py.

Nevertheless, I found this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18503
So all I did was installing tensorflow version 1.5 by executing:

```sh
pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed tensorflow-gpu==1.5
```

Afterwards it did run through errorless and the training worked fine.