# unity ML Agents and external data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, machine-learning, ml-agent

Quite new to Unity, I'm more from a machine learning background. Planning to use ML Agents, and write some custom python / tensorflow scripts for it.

Is it possible to train based on data from my harddrive additionally to unity environment data? So for example having additional image data to feed as input to the network beside the Unity camera?

Haven't really seen that so far in the examples and documentation.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking if you can read files from the hard drive in Unity? Are you asking if Unity can start a python interpreter process? I'm not really sure what your question really is.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50070717/1092820) will help answer your question

Comment: I'm asking if the ml_agents training script that I want to write can also use files from my harddrive and incorporate that into the training

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you can express it in a fixed-length sequence of `Vector3`, `Vector2`, `float`, `int`, `bool`, `Quaternion`, or a fixed one-hot, sure no problem. Just include them with `AddVectorObs` in `CollectObservations`:

```
public override void CollectObservations()
{
    //internal info
    AddVectorObs(gameObject.transform.rotation.z);
    AddVectorObs(gameObject.transform.position);

    Vector3 externalInfo1 = ExternalInfoGetter.StaticGetInfo1();
    AddVectorObs(externalInfo1);

    float externalInfo2 = ExternalInfoGetter.StaticGetInfo2();
    AddVectorObs(externalInfo2);
}
```

See [the documentation on designing agents](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Learning-Environment-Design-Agents.md) for more info, including info on how to implement one-hot features and advice on normalizing the inputs.